# We can't download the rss lib `Rome` for Java now?

Tags: java, rss, atom-feed, rome

I'm looking for a java rss lib, and I found [rome](http://java.net/projects/rome). But there is nothing can be [downloaded](http://java.net/projects/rome/downloads) now. What happened to this project? Where can I find it?

Or is there any other good `rss` or `atom` libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably something temporarily wrong with their downloads. You can still find it here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/rome/rome/